# Timer delayed by resizing window

Tags: objective-c, resize, nstimer, delay, nswindow

I have a NSTimer who ticks every 0.x seconds. I also have a button that enables to show or hide controls hereby resizing the window.

I noticed however that by clicking the button and resizing the window significantly delays the timer, for example if i repeatedly click the resize button my timer my run several seconds late.

Can anybody advice me on how to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Try adding it to the common run loop modes:

```
// alloc/init your timer here
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:yourTimer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

Comment: Doubt if NSEventTrackingRunLoopMode events would block NSRunLoopCommonModes timers.

Comment: Is `NSEventTrackingRunLoopMode` not in the common modes? I forget.

Comment: I suppose it isn't. I'll fix my answer.

Comment: Actually, wait: "For Cocoa applications, this set includes the default, modal, and event tracking modes by default." from the docs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i tried adding it to the NSRunLoopCommonMode after starting the timer, but unfortunately it still runs behind, do you have any idea what else might help?

Comment: If you're using an `NSAnimation`, you could try setting the animation mode to `NSAnimationBlocking`, though this will let user events go through which might be an even bigger issue during resize…

Comment: I am using `[window setFrame:newFrame display:YES animate:YES]` how can i configure the animation mode than? I don't have explicit control over the animation part (P.S. I greatly appreciate you following up on me)

Comment: @Wevah you have any more advice for that specific case?

Comment: No, I don't. :/ Does the timer fire immediately after the resize?